# Proper way of configuring Jetty request timeout

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I would like to drop any request which takes longer than x seconds, and attend to the new request on Jetty.

I thought this should be a very usual thing that people do, but apparently not. I cannot find any documentation on doing anything similar to this.

I configured thread_pool idleTimeout, which understandably doesn't have any effect on this.

I also configured connector idle timeout. I have an endpoint which simply sleeps the thread. I thought that the idle timeout should kill this thread, as it is obviously idle, but that didn't happen either.

I was wondering what is the proper way of handling these scenarios.

Comment: Jetty server or Jetty client?

Comment: Idle Timeout does not kill the thread, it will shutdown the Connection and then allow the thread to properly unravel via various IOExceptions.   Killing/Interrupting Java threads is highly unreliable and not a valid timeout expiration behavior.

Comment: It is jetty server. I think I understand the complications better now. But this is such a common usecase. When you say " it will shutdown the Connection and then allow the thread to properly unravel via various IOExceptions", how exactly that happens? Can you give me a link or something for information.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Out of curiosity, why is `Thread.interrupt()` (e.g. by way of `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` "highly unreliable and not a valid timeout expiration behavior"? Are there any links you could share for me to read about this?